# Yii2 трансформировать дату в виде строчки в дату в виде числа

Tags: php, yii2, datetime, timestamp

Есть функция, которая трансформирует дату в формате '1671380485' в что-то на подобие 'December 18, 2022'.

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('1671380485', 'long')
```

Мне нужна функция, которая будет делать наоборот, например, трансформировать '2022-12-21' в подобный формат '1671380485'

Answer (score 1):

Нашел вот такую вот штуку

strtotime()

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTimeImmutable('2022-12-21'); // устанавливаем необходимую дату
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // получаем дату в нужном формате
echo $date->getTimestamp(); // получаем дату в timestamp
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]